# AJAX 404 after Upgrade to TYPO3 8.7

Tags: ajax, typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x

I have two identical installations with regard to everything except for the TYPO3 Version. Both are fresh installs, so the databases should be normal.

In my extension, I make an AJAX call to a page that holds nothing but my plugin with the Content-type:application/html.

In TYPO3 v. 7.6.16, the Ajax response is successful.

In TYPO3 v. 8.7, the Ajax call fails with a 404: not found.

The urls are identical, apart from variation in the cHash.

Does anyone know why this is the case, and what I need to do to correct the situation?

Comment: If cHash is different maybe in TYPO3 8.7 is $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['cHashIncludePageId'] = true; For new installations, this option is ON by default. See security issue https://typo3.org/news/article/cache-flooding-in-typo3-frontend/

Comment: Do you still get a 404 if you switch to `Development` context or is there an error message then?

Comment: @undko The Typo3 Context is set to Development, and no error, sadly. If I add the pageType through the f:form pageType parameter, then I do get the following error, though it doesn't tell us much more... "Ajax request - error: Not Found"

Comment: @HeinzSchilling; could you elaborate a little more on the cHash flooding? I think there's a chance that might have something to do with it.

Comment: @HeinzSchilling, I tried adding the line below to my LocalConfiguration.php file though and nothing changed.

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['cHashIncludePageId'] = true;

Comment: @hrta Have you read the link above? There is the description of Cache flooding. When you set $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['cHashIncludePageId'] = false; your cache can be flooded, but pageUid is not a component of cHash calculation. Does your Ajax works with "false"? Then you habe to include pageUid in your request and your cHash calculation and turn $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['cHashIncludePageId'] = true;

Comment: @HeinzSchilling,
Ok; tried setting it to false. Still nothing. The error is: "Page Not Found
Reason: Request parameters could not be validated (&cHash empty)"

Comment: @HeinzSchilling; There also seems to be a broken parameter attached to the end of the url: "&_=1492180598322"

Comment: @HeinzSchilling; I found that if I set [FE] [pageNotFoundOnCHashError] = 0, then the ajax call works... I guess I'm now wondering; what it the downside of setting it this way, or whether there is a way to set the cHash for my Ajax call. Thanks for all of your help and advice.

Comment: Is it safe to deactivate pageNotFoundOnCHashError?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the cHash and avoid the TYPO3_CONF_VARS settings, by passing a js variable with »f:uri.action« into the ajax url in fluid.

Fluid template:

```
<script>
  var ajaxUrl = '<f:uri.action action="list" pageType="123456"/>';

  $.ajax({
      url: ajaxUrl,
      [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

look here: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/79970
Go to installtool and uncheck: "pageNotFoundOnCHashError". Thats does it for me.